# Kmeans clustering in TF 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

There was a kMeans clustering function in TF 1.13 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans.

I was wondering if there is a similar function for TF 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans?hl=en#example

Reference: Tensorflow 2.0 compatibility for v1: `tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans`

Comment: @dhruv, FYI, I'm trying to find the same right now. This is the best I've found so far with TF2.0's eager execute.